# How do I shows column headers of main report on each page when subreport renders on more than one pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have few subreports in a sql main report(.rdl file) using `VS`/`SSRS 2008`.
The subreports start approximately on the middle of the page in the main report detail section. I have one group in main report, shows header information and pass one parameter - `ReportID` to each subreport.
I also have checked both:

1. Row Headers – “Repeat header rows on each page” and
2. Column Headers – “Repeat header columns on each page”

on `General` tab of `Tablix` properties of the main report.
If I have few detail lines in the subreport, so that all can be rendered on page one, everything is ok.
If I have more detail lines in the subreport so that it's not possible to print all on one page, the subreport renders from the fist page and moves on to page two, three and so on.

When I have more than one page of data in the subreport, it is also started on page one, and continues renders on second page and so on...
However, it doesn't show the main report's column/row headers on subsequent pages of the subreports?
I've noticed that when next item/`ReportID` starts in my main report group, it prints column header only on the first page but not any subsequent page and so on...

I also tried to check only ONE, either

1. Row Headers – “Repeat header rows on each page” OR
2. Column Headers – “Repeat header columns on each page”

on general tab of Tablix properties of the main report BUT didn’t work?

Any ideas how to print header info on each page when subreport has more than one page data?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is always fun in SSRS.

Have you looked at the page size/interactive of the subreport? This may stop the subreport paging, but I don't know if it's what you want.

[An older article on pagination](http://blogs.msdn.com/bwelcker/archive/2005/08/19/Alien-Lanes-_2800_Logical-and-Physical-Pagination-Rules_2900_.aspx)

[And a newer one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8cbc81d9-c86d-4dd7-9741-a15e79b8dcd9/)

Answer (score 0):

Presently I am encountering the same problem.  In a previous SSRS report we got it to work by putting our tablix inside a single-cell list item so that the headers were repeated.  Now I am working on a different report, and when I try the same thing I'm getting this error:

```
[rsInvalidDetailDataGrouping] The tablix ‘tablixOpportunitySummary’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.
```

I've searched extensively, but this is the only link which indicates an known problem in SSRS.  At the time of this post it contained 4 workarounds:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/337720/katmai-reporting-services-2008-tablix-control-repeat-column-headers-does-not-work#

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I think this is what you are looking for:

You need to go to **tablix properties > General** and check the option **Keep header visible while scrolling**. Then go to column/row groups in the advanced mode, chose your static row and set the **Fixed Data** mode to `True`, **Repeat on new page** to `True` and **Keep with group** to `After`.

Here is probably the best reference: [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/13/repeat-header-keep-header-visible-in-tables-in-rs-2008/)